# Change the Keyboard Layout Handler item image indicator in the LXDE panel

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu, keyboard-layout, indicator, lxde

I'm using an install of lubuntu on a macbook pro, french layout. When I pick the standard pc105 keyboard model in the Keyboard Layout Handler, everything works fine, I see the small "FR" image indicator in the panel as shown below.

[image: pc105]

But when I pick the macbbok79 keyboard model, which I have to for this install, I get a big "MACINTOSH" text in the panel indicator, it's unnecessary big, and reduce significantly the space for other indicators (tasks, and so on...) in the bottom panel. As shown below.

[image: macbook79]

I searched the web with no luck, any ideas how to customize this "MACINTOSH" indicator ? Looks like a weird behaviour anyway, as the layout didn't change it's still "FR", so I don't understand why it would show "MACINTOSH", is it doesn't show "PC" when I pick "pc105"...

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. *It's a workaround as I still think it's a weird behaviour to display the keyboard model family instead of the layout code.*

You have to go to this folder `/usr/share/lxpanel/images/xkb-flags-cust` and create a `macintosh.png` image.
In my case, I used a link to `fr.png` to avoid creating a new image.

```
sudo ln -s fr.png macintosh.png
```

You can do the same in the folder `/usr/share/lxpanel/images/xkb-flags` (that's when you prefer to dispplay the flags in the keyboard layout indicator).